# The following packages have unmet dependencies, what should i do?

Tags: package-management

```
packages have unmet dependencies:
openstack-dashboard : Depends: python: (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme but it is not installed
```

Status of /var/lib/dpkg/status

```
Package: openstack-dashboard
Status: install ok half-configured
Priority: extra
Section: net
Installed-Size: 15121
Maintainer: Chuck Short <zulcss@ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: horizon
Version: 1:2014.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0
Config-Version: 1:2014.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0
Depends: adduser, apache2 | httpd, libapache2-mod-wsgi (>= 2.3), python-django-    horizon (= 1:2014.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0), python: (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2)
Recommends: openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
```

Comment: have you run 'sudo apt-get install -f'

Comment: Omveer, did you search for the answer to your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands

`sudo apt-get -f install` (To install missing dependencies)

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` (To configure dpkg)